# Random numbers in java generated JMeter testplan

Tags: jmeter

I programmaticaly generate my jmeter test plans in java code.

```
HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
threadGroupHashTree.add(loopController);
HashTree threadGroupHashTree;
String employeeId = "1";
HTTPSamplerProxy hs = HttpSampler.createHttpSampler(data, "http://test.de/employee/" + employeeId, "GET", "");
threadGroupHashTree.add(hs);
```

Then I start this testplan:

```
StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = setupJMeter(threadGroupHashTree);
jmeter.configure(threadGroupHashTree);
jmeter.run();
```

It's works. Now I need to send requests with different employeeId (random). In JMeter GUI we can use random functions for randomize our tests.

Provides JMeter API such functionality? How can we randomize our requests? Or we must replace LoopController with for loops?

Comment: can't you use java's random?

Comment: You can add random variable component to your threadgroup and use its functionality to generate random employeeID or use counter component to generate employeeID in a sequence.

Comment: 1) Java's random doesn't work with LoopController - it will be executed only one time and then LoopController repeats same value many times.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use JMeter's [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) normally like:

   ```
   String employeeId = "${__Random(1,999,)}"
   ```

   Just make sure to have [ApacheJMeter_functions](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_functions) JAR in your project classpath
2. You can use [RandomUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomUtils.html) class like

   ```
   String employeeId = String.valueOf(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(1,1000));
   ```
3. You can use [ThreadLocalRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) class like

   ```
   String employeeId = String.valueOf(java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1,1000));
   ```

Any of the approaches will return a random number each time it will be called.

See [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article and [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/) example project to learn more about creating JMeter tests programmatically.

Comment: 1) in first  case the values are notreplaced - I have http://test.de/employee/${__Random(1,999,)}/ in test plan.

Comment: 2) in third case the generated value is always the same.